# Can anyone explain the difference between these two forms of PID controllers?

Tags: schematics, transfer-function, pid-controller, math, formula-derivation

Usually, when people talk about PID controller, I think of the "parallel form" of PID controllers, I know how it is derived (we just need to add all 3 three P I D controllers together). This is the first time I have ever seen the "series form" of PID controller (being second year engineering student). Can you tell me how it's derived and how it's drawn in a diagram? Thanks.

[image]

Comment: In the series form shown, Ki and Kd have 1/time or time units (thus Ti and Td are often used), and Kp carries the output/process units in all 3 terms. It is more common in industry, I suspect for historical reasons.

Comment: I think you have an explanation [here](http://www.acsysteme.com/en/serial-or-parallel-pid) on the three possible forms. Please keep in mind that any of these forms is supplemented with a filter to form the *filtered PID*. I covered the subject in an [APEC seminar](https://cbasso.pagesperso-orange.fr/Downloads/PPTs/Chris%20Basso%20APEC%20seminar%202012.pdf) in 2012.

Answer (score 1):

The function is the same in both these rudimentary forms of controller.

The only difference is in the values of the (constant) parameters and how (or if) they interact when you adjust what you have to adjust.

However most would call what is referred to as "Series form" above as "Ideal". The series form was what was easier to implement with pneumatic controllers and has more interactions between the terms.